# Compiler not identify warnings, and how can I solve them?

Tags: warnings, keil, cortex-m

I have 4 warnings the compiler not identify:
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kjRA.png)

When I enter to Arm-Math library, all this errors are appear:
[link 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhyIF.png)

Why the compiler not recognize them?
And the main question, how can I solve those errors?
Arm-Math is official library, it should not make problems...
This is my code:

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * <h2><center>&copy; Copyright (c) 2020 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.</center></h2>
  *
  * This software component is licensed by ST under BSD 3-Clause license,
  * the "License"; You may not use this file except in compliance with the
  * License. You may obtain a copy of the License at:
  *                        opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* USER CODE END Header */

/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#define ARM_MATH_CM4
#include "arm_math.h"                                                                               // for FFT

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */
#ifdef __GNUC__
  /* With GCC, small printf (option LD Linker->Libraries->Small printf
     set to 'Yes') calls __io_putchar() */
  #define PUTCHAR_PROTOTYPE int __io_putchar(int ch)
#else
  #define PUTCHAR_PROTOTYPE int fputc(int ch, FILE *f)
#endif /* __GNUC__ */
/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */
/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
UART_HandleTypeDef huart2;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */
void startFFT (void);
/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* FFT settings */
#define SAMPLES                    512                              /* 256 real party and 256 imaginary parts */
#define FFT_SIZE                SAMPLES / 2                         /* FFT size is always the same size as we have samples, so 256 in our case */
  
/* Global variables */
float32_t Input[SAMPLES];
float32_t Output[FFT_SIZE];
int32_t threshold = 50000;
int32_t neighbor_threshold = 1000;

/* FFT */
arm_cfft_radix4_instance_f32 S;                                         /* ARM CFFT module */
float32_t maxValue;                                                     /* Max FFT value is stored here */
uint32_t maxIndex;                                                      /* Index in Output array where max value is */
/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */
    
    /* UART */
    float32_t sine[256] = {1,-0.866025404,0.5,3.06287E-16,-0.5,0.866025404,-1,0.866025404,-0.5,8.57495E-16,0.5,-0.866025404,1,-0.866025404,0.5,6.86051E-15,-0.5,0.866025404,-1,0.866025404,-0.5,3.18506E-15,0.5,-0.866025404,1,-0.866025404,0.5,9.80227E-16,-0.5,0.866025404,-1,0.866025404,-0.5,1.95991E-15,0.5,-0.866025404,1,-0.866025404,0.5,9.3108E-15,-0.5,0.866025404,-1,0.866025404,-0.5,-6.37066E-15,0.5,-0.866025404,1,-0.866025404,0.5,3.43052E-15,-0.5,0.866025404,-1,0.866025404,-0.5,-2.89121E-14,0.5,-0.866025404,1,-0.866025404,0.5,-2.44975E-15,-0.5,0.866025404,-1,0.866025404,-0.5,-2.30318E-14,0.5,-0.866025404,1,-0.866025404,0.5,-8.33003E-15,-0.5,0.866025404,-1,0.866025404,-0.5,-1.71515E-14,0.5,-0.866025404,1,-0.866025404,0.5,1.42114E-14,-0.5,0.866025404,-1,0.866025404,-0.5,-3.9693E-14,0.5,-0.866025404,1,-0.866025404,0.5,-2.00906E-14,-0.5,0.866025404,-1,0.866025404,-0.5,2.30307E-14,0.5,-0.866025404,1,-0.866025404,0.5,3.08725E-14,-0.5,0.866025404,-1,0.866025404,-0.5,-2.79324E-14,0.5,-0.866025404,1,-0.866025404,0.5,2.49923E-14,-0.5,0.866025404,-1,0.866025404,-0.5,-2.20521E-14,0.5,-0.866025404,1,-0.866025404,0.5,1.9112E-14,-0.5,0.866025404,-1,0.866025404,-0.5,-7.30153E-14,0.5,-0.866025404,1,-0.866025404,0.5,1.32317E-14,-0.5,0.866025404,-1,0.866025404,-0.5,-1.02916E-14,0.5,-0.866025404,1,-0.866025404,0.5,6.41949E-14,-0.5,0.866025404,-1,0.866025404,-0.5,-6.12547E-14,0.5,-0.866025404,1,-0.866025404,0.5,1.47115E-15,-0.5,0.866025404,-1,0.866025404,-0.5,5.83124E-14,0.5,-0.866025404,1,-0.866025404,0.5,5.24343E-14,-0.5,0.866025404,-1,0.866025404,-0.5,7.34926E-15,0.5,-0.866025404,1,-0.866025404,0.5,4.6554E-14,-0.5,0.866025404,-1,0.866025404,-0.5,-4.36139E-14,0.5,-0.866025404,1,-0.866025404,0.5,9.75172E-14,-0.5,0.866025404,-1,0.866025404,-0.5,-3.77336E-14,0.5,-0.866025404,1,-0.866025404,0.5,-2.205E-14,-0.5,0.866025404,-1,0.866025404,-0.5,-3.18533E-14,0.5,-0.866025404,1,-0.866025404,0.5,-2.79302E-14,-0.5,0.866025404,-1,0.866025404,-0.5,-2.5973E-14,0.5,-0.866025404,1,-0.866025404,0.5,7.98763E-14,-0.5,0.866025404,-1,0.866025404,-0.5,-2.00928E-14,0.5,-0.866025404,1,-0.866025404,0.5,-3.96908E-14};

    for (int32_t i= 0 ; i < SAMPLES ; i+=2)
    {
        Input[i] = sine [i/2];
        Input[i+1] = 0;
    }
    /* USER CODE END 1 */
  

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
        printf("Hello-World \r\n");
        HAL_Delay(1500);

        startFFT();
        printf("6 \r\n");
        printf("FFT Max Value: %.2f: \r\n", maxValue);
        printf("FFT Max Frequency: %0.2f: \r\n", ((int) maxIndex * 93.75));
        HAL_Delay(2000);
        printf("FFT Argument: \r\n");
        for(int16_t i=0; i<SAMPLES/2; i++)
        {
            printf("%.2f Hz: %.2f \r\n", (i * 93.75), Output[i]);
            HAL_Delay(2000);
        }
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_PeriphCLKInitTypeDef PeriphClkInit = {0};

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_MSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSIState = RCC_MSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSICalibrationValue = 0;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSIClockRange = RCC_MSIRANGE_6;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_MSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 1;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 40;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV7;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = RCC_PLLQ_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLR = RCC_PLLR_DIV2;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_4) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  PeriphClkInit.PeriphClockSelection = RCC_PERIPHCLK_USART2;
  PeriphClkInit.Usart2ClockSelection = RCC_USART2CLKSOURCE_PCLK1;
  if (HAL_RCCEx_PeriphCLKConfig(&PeriphClkInit) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage 
  */
  if (HAL_PWREx_ControlVoltageScaling(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief USART2 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 1 */
  huart2.Instance = USART2;
  huart2.Init.BaudRate = 9600;
  huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart2.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart2.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart2.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart2.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  huart2.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
  huart2.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PA5 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_5;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */
PUTCHAR_PROTOTYPE
{
  /* Place your implementation of fputc here */
  /* e.g. write a character to the EVAL_COM1 and Loop until the end of transmission */
  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t *)&ch, 1, 0xFFFF);

  return ch;
}
    /* FFT */
void startFFT (void)
{
    printf("1 \r\n");
    arm_cfft_radix4_init_f32(&S, FFT_SIZE, 0, 1);                       // Initialize the CFFT/CIFFT module, intFlag = 0, doBitReverse = 1// @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ need to be added to Init in main area in the ANC code @@@@@@@@@@@
    printf("2 \r\n");
    arm_cfft_radix4_f32(&S, Input);                                                 // Process the data through the CFFT/CIFFT module // @@@@@@@@@@@ Doing FFT on the input, and save it their (?) // print the result of real and imag for checking    
    printf("3 \r\n");
    arm_cmplx_mag_f32(Input, Output, FFT_SIZE);                         // Process the data through the Complex Magniture Module for calculating the magnitude at each bin
    printf("4 \r\n");
    arm_max_f32(Output, FFT_SIZE, &maxValue, &maxIndex);        // Calculates maxValue and returns corresponding value
    printf("5 \r\n");
    return;

}

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */

  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(char *file, uint32_t line)
{ 
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     tex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */

/************************ (C) COPYRIGHT STMicroelectronics *****END OF FILE****/
```

I tried to use this code in CubeMxIDE and it work fine. but in Keil, it make problems

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code has successfully compiled. The error/warnings are probably live content-assist warnings from the IDE.